# NTFS get the MFT entry by the record id in $DATA attribute list

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, mft

I'm trying to code a simple NTFS parser in C and in this [`video`](https://youtu.be/CXAtzB3mOMw?si=tQ7dErRq7xcJt_Dj&t=1516) explains that in attribute list $DATA, there is a file record id, this is an unique id in the MFT table that identifies the entry, he says that to get the MFT entry just multiply that id by the file record size, in this case 1024 and you will get the MFT entry byte offset:

```
mft_entry_byte_offset = file_record_id * file_record_size
```

Using WinHex I just selected a random 1.5GB file with many fragments and using the formula it does not points to the MFT entry

Here is part of the data list, each entry is get using this structure: [`ATTRIBUTE_LIST_ENTRY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/attribute-list-entry)

```
80 00 00 00 20 00 00 1A A3 A3 01 00 00 00 00 00
5B CC 07 00 00 00 32 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

80 00 00 00 20 00 00 1A DD 00 02 00 00 00 00 00
D7 BD 07 00 00 00 77 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

80 00 00 00 20 00 00 1A 51 1E 02 00 00 00 00 00
61 54 03 00 00 00 44 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

First in the list is:

```
record_id = 5B CC 07 00 = 511067
mft_entry = 511067 * 1024 = 523 332 608 (byte offset)
sector = 523 332 608 / 512 = 1 022 134
```

Using Active Disk Editor if I go to the entry 511067 it says that is in the 63 490 486 sector

I know that Windows API can access the file record id and get the entry but I would like to get it without using the API

Comment: If, after a few days, you don't get an answer here, ask *instead* at https://stackoverflow.com/